# PHP RPC: how do I get the "min_fee" value so I do not exceed balance + min_fee when sending a transaction?

Tags: daemon, rpc, transaction-fees, payment-integration

I keep getting an error when I want to send my entire balance (not using `sweep_all` but `transfer_split`).

It says that the "`needed_money + min_fee > balance_subtotal`". So, I need to at least make sure I send `$transfer_amount-$min_fee` to avoid this error.

Given the above, how do I calculate the `min_fee`?

I am using ["monero-integrations/monerophp"](https://github.com/monero-integrations/monerophp/tree/master) to connect to the wallet rpc.